# using multiple nhibernate versions in a web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, structuremap

I am maintaining a web application that by design uses NHibernate 2.1.0.4.

I'm incorporating an assembly that uses StructureMap and has a newer version of NHibernate, 3.3.0.4.

My web app is failing the moment I try to create a session instance:

```
var sessionFactory = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>();
```

With a StructureMap 202 error.

Apparently I can't use the interface from the older version, but I need to maintain the older version for the rest of the application.

How can I incorporate the newer version of the assembly while not losing the older one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have references to two versions of the same assembly in the same application.